# Creating polygons from points in Carto

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, carto, polygon-creation

Using Carto, I am trying to create shapefiles of regions using points([Link to Dataset in Carto](https://vacasa.carto.com/u/st-braund/dataset/wa_seattle_metro) ) with a shared column value to group by. I've included 3 photographs. 1st photograph of the points outlining the shape. the second photo is my desired result which I have drawn out by hand. The third photo is an attempt that does not meet my desired result.

I am using the analysis tool provided by Carto, running a concave hull and have tried various target percent values and without the desired results. For this example I've included a target percent of 80 and the result is shown in a photograph at the bottom. The code is provided below

```sql
  SELECT row_number() over() as cartodb_id,
         territoryid as category,
         ST_ConcaveHull(
             ST_Collect(the_geom), 
             0.8, 
             false
          ) AS the_geom,
         count(1) as count_vals
    FROM (
         SELECT *
           FROM ( SELECT * FROM "st-braund".bd_regions_1 ) _camshaft_category_filter
          WHERE territoryid IN (3)
         ) _analysis_source
GROUP BY territoryid
```

[image: Shape Outline with Points]

[image: Desired Shapefile]

[image: Failed Attempt]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? I can see two concave polygons the second with a higher percent value, so I don't understand where the issue is. What do you mean by `poor results`? What were you expecting?

Comment: how's the result in the range between 0.99 and 0.90?

Comment: thanks for the input @ThingumaBob! at 99 seemed to have closest to the desired result.

Comment: @JorgeSanz is it possible to write an order by statement after the group by statement?

Comment: yep @Sbraund, you can always wrap your query and put your ordering outside `WITH a AS (myquery) SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY b`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for the above problem was to

Create Lines from the points --> Close the Lines --> then make a polygon from closed lines.

```
SELECT row_number() over() AS cartodb_id, *,
  ST_Length(the_geom_webmercator::geography) as length FROM (
  SELECT territoryid as category
   , ST_MakeLine(the_geom ORDER BY bd_territories_coords_id asc) AS the_geom_webmercator 
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM "st-braund".template_localities_1 ) _line_sequential
  GROUP BY territoryid ) _cdb_analysis_line_sequential
```

---